# How to Add color behind the color text like this image?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[color behind text Example:#ffffff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0P2u.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download Color Highlight, it's an extension on VS Code.